# what is wrong with the while loop here ? C basics

Tags: c

I am trying to count the number of letters of a word before the space. For eg. "Hello how" is my input string and I am trying to count the number of letters in the first word.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char a[30];
  int count = 0;
  printf("Enter the string.\n"); // Enter hello how as string here.
  gets(a);
  for ( i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++ )
      {
      while( a[i+1] != ' ' )
      count++;
      }                        
  printf("%d\n",count);
 }
```

This is a small part of a bigger code, I am actually expecting the value of count to be 5 but it gets into some sort of infinite loop which I am unable to figure out. If I use if instead of while , I get the expected answer. I know gets is not very reliable and I will not use once I get better at programming so it will be kind of you to post your answer about the loop instead of gets. Thank You.

Comment: Your count variable is somewhat pointless, as you can use more than one conditional in your test expression, then use `i` as your printed result. `for (i=0; a[i] && (a[i] != ' '); ++i);`. And don't use `gets()`. Its evil. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake here in the code about the null character but it was just a typing mistake I did here. @WhozCraig: About the loop yes, thats what I meant when I said its a part of a bigger program , I want that to be my outer loop in which I can then put more statements.

Comment: Ah, if that is the case you can still use a single for-statement inside for char-counting the current word. It just gets a little trickier what to do afterward. But glad it made sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NUL character is written with a backslash (`\`), not forward slash (`/`).

```
for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Furthermore, the inner loop will not terminate because you're not incrementing `i`.

```
while (a[i] != ' ') {
    i++;
    count++;
}
```

Actually, you should not really have two loops. One loop is all you need.

```
for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0' && a[i] != ' '; i++) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Or simply `for (i = 0; a[i] && a[i] != ' '; i++);` where i will be the number of letters in the first word.

Answer (score 4):

The expression within the *while* statement does not depend on `count`. So with every iteration of the *while* loop the `count` gets incremented, but that has no influence on the *while* conditional, hence it will loop ad infinitum or never, depending on the character at `a[i+1]`.

In addition to that, the conditional statement for the *for* loop is not written correctly either. The string escape for a NUL character is `\0` (backslash). Or you can just compare against a `0` literal, which has exactly the same outcome (though when it comes to the subtleties of C it does not mean *exactly* the same, but that's splitting hairs).

Comment: This was the correct answer to the question, though the observation about NUL is also correct. (You could also just write the numeric value 0, which is NUL's ASCII/Unicode value; that would be more C-idiomatic.)

Comment: @keshlam: I was writing that into an Edit just when you wrote the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `'\0'` instead of `'/0'` in the for loop condition and also the while loop condition will never be false because *i* remains the same